# Как запустить функцию?

Tags: html, javascript

Есть форма для отправки данных.

Пример мы повесили onclick на checkbox, но функция не хочет запускаться.

http://jsfiddle.net/kmzo5nem/

Текст ошибки: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Answer (score 1):

1. Измени id элемента

   input id="uCheck1" onclick="uCheck();" type="checkbox"> Check
2. Поставь функцию в head или в body, а не вызывай ее по onLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы этот заработало, нужно в первую очередь, поменять настройки JS для фидла: поставить вместо `onLoad` - `No wrap - in <body>`.

А также определиться, что вам нужно обрабатывать в JS, если вы хотите обрабатывать клик на чекбокс, то нужно убрать форму, а если хотите форму, то убрать клик на чекбокс и добавить в JS обработку данных из формы.

Вот рабочий вариант для чекбокса: http://jsfiddle.net/kmzo5nem/2/

Comment: При нажатии на checkox открывается еще одно поле для заполнения.

А форма нужна для отправки данных.